# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>

Tags: java, hadoop, schema, avro

I have this script and it works on local machine.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "ToParquet");

    job.setJarByClass(ToParquet.class);

    job.setMapperClass(BasicsMapper.class);
    job.setMapperClass(RatingsMapper.class);

    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs:///title.basics.tsv"), TextInputFormat.class, BasicsMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs:///title.ratings.tsv"), TextInputFormat.class, RatingsMapper.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Void.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(GenericRecord.class);

    job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroParquetOutputFormat.class);
    AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, getSchema());
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs:///to_parquet_output"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

However when I try to run it on HFDS environment this following error message shows up.

[image]

I don't know what's going on. If someone can help me, I appreciate.

Comment: You need to create and submit a fat jar and make sure your Avro versions are consistent with Parquet. You could also use Spark which comes with Avro and Parquet support